# Mips exception at PC

Tags: assembly, mips, spim, mars-simulator, qtspim

Currently trying to develop a mips program for generating a math sequence. However, i keep getting a Mips exception at PC.

```
terms:
    addi $sp, $sp, -12 #decrement the stack pointer by 12
    sw $ra, 8($sp) 
    sw $s1, 4($sp)  
    sw $s0, 0($sp) 
    add $s0, $a0, $0
    li $s1, 16
    la  $a0, sequence   # display sequence
    li  $v0, 4
    syscall

print:
    add $a0, $zero, $s0
    li $v0, 1
    syscall

    addi $s1, $s1, -1
    beq $s1, $0, quit
    addi $a0, $s0, 0
    jal initiliazeCompute

    addi $s0, $v0, 0
    j print

    quit:
        la $a0, endline
        jr $ra

initiliazeCompute:
    addi $v0, $0, 0
    li $t2, 10

    Compute: 
        rem $t1, $a0, $t2 # $t1 is units digit of current term
        mul $t1, $t1, $t1 # square that value
        add $v0, $v0, $t1 # add this value to next term
        div $a0, $a0, $t2 # discard units digit of current term
        jr $ra # return to calling routine
```

Comment: Gonna need more info. It runs fine for me.

Comment: Well, what is the value of PC when the exception occurs? And which instruction in your code does that correspond to?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using QTSpim (as suggested by your tag), you generally need to include a bit of code to signify where to start, as well as to quit. Try adding the following code at the beginning:

```
.globl main
.text

main:
     jal terms    #I'm assuming terms is the first routine to be executed
     j print    #jump to print. When print is done, it jumps to exit

exit:
     .end    #ends the program
     li $v0, 10    #syscall code for exiting
     syscall
```

Note that you'll also need to add a `jr $ra` at the end of terms, to return to main (then print will be called after the terms are initialized). Then, add `j exit` to the quit label under print, so that when print is done it jumps up to the exit routine.

Now the problem is that `sequence` and `endline` are not defined, so calling `la $a0, sequence` and `la $a0, endline` won't work. I got rid of `la $a0, endline` as I didn't see its purpose. You should define sequence after a `.data` label at the beginning (before the `.text` label). As an example, here is what it'd look like if sequence is an array of integers set to 0:

```
.globl main

.data 
    sequence: .word 0:8    #initialize sequence to array of 8 integers (value 0)

.text

 main: ...
```

In the branch instruction in `print`, you have `beq $s1, $0, quit`. This should be `beq $s1, $zero, quit` instead.

With the above changes, it ran fine when I tried it. For reference, here's the final code that I used:

```
.globl main
.data 
    sequence: .word 0:8 #sequence := array of 8 integers (value 0)
.text
main:
    jal terms #start by executing terms
    j print #once terms has run, jump to print

exit:
    .end #exit program
    li $v0, 10
    syscall

terms:
    addi $sp, $sp, -12 #decrement the stack pointer by 12
    sw $ra, 8($sp) 
    sw $s1, 4($sp)  
    sw $s0, 0($sp) 
    add $s0, $a0, $0
    li $s1, 16
    la  $a0, sequence   # display sequence
    li  $v0, 4
    syscall
    jr $ra

print:
    add $a0, $zero, $s0
    li $v0, 1
    syscall

    addi $s1, $s1, -1
    beq $s1, $zero, quit
    addi $a0, $s0, 0
    jal initiliazeCompute

    addi $s0, $v0, 0
    j print

    quit:
        # la $a0, endline - this isn’t necessary
        j exit #jump to exit routine

initiliazeCompute:
    addi $v0, $0, 0
    li $t2, 10

    Compute: 
        rem $t1, $a0, $t2 # $t1 is units digit of current term
        mul $t1, $t1, $t1 # square that value
        add $v0, $v0, $t1 # add this value to next term
        div $a0, $a0, $t2 # discard units digit of current term
        jr $ra # return to calling routine
```

Hope that helps!